# Node.js Log location in Heroku Deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku, next.js, nodes

Im trying run my Node app in Heroku. It deployes with no error but it crashes at the start. the log below is not clear what the issue is and when I try to look at the suggested log at .npm/_logs/2021-04-22T19_59_52_474Z-debug.log, It says the file is not found. I tried to bash into my app from command prompt and the folder .npm doesnt even exist. So wondering how i can access the mentioned log file to see whats going on?

$ ls

app  bin  dev  etc  lib  lib64  lost+found  proc  sbin  sys  tmp usr  var /

**$ cd app ~**

$ ls

**LICENSE  README.md  app.json  node_modules  package-lock.json  package.json  pages  public  src**

```
2021-04-22T19:59:42.811730+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-04-22T19:59:47.698499+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-04-22T19:59:52.168600+00:00 app[web.1]: npm info it worked if it ends with ok
2021-04-22T19:59:52.169476+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb cli [ '/app/.heroku/node/bin/node',
2021-04-22T19:59:52.169750+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb cli   '/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm',
2021-04-22T19:59:52.170011+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb cli   'start' ]
2021-04-22T19:59:52.170326+00:00 app[web.1]: npm info using npm@6.14.12
2021-04-22T19:59:52.170710+00:00 app[web.1]: npm info using node@v10.24.1
2021-04-22T19:59:52.171113+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb config Skipping project config: /app/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
2021-04-22T19:59:52.379409+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
2021-04-22T19:59:52.382021+00:00 app[web.1]: npm info lifecycle heroku-nextjs@1.0.0~prestart: heroku-nextjs@1.0.0
2021-04-22T19:59:52.386151+00:00 app[web.1]: npm info lifecycle heroku-nextjs@1.0.0~start: heroku-nextjs@1.0.0
2021-04-22T19:59:52.405835+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-22T19:59:52.405837+00:00 app[web.1]: > heroku-nextjs@1.0.0 start /app
2021-04-22T19:59:52.405838+00:00 app[web.1]: > next start -p $PORT
2021-04-22T19:59:52.405838+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-22T19:59:52.440871+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: next: not found
2021-04-22T19:59:52.443031+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb lifecycle heroku-nextjs@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
2021-04-22T19:59:52.448691+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb lifecycle heroku-nextjs@1.0.0~start: PATH: /app/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/app/node_modules/.bin:/app/.heroku/node/bin:/app/.heroku/yarn/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/app/bin:/app/node_modules/.bin
2021-04-22T19:59:52.449080+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb lifecycle heroku-nextjs@1.0.0~start: CWD: /app
2021-04-22T19:59:52.449413+00:00 app[web.1]: npm info lifecycle heroku-nextjs@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
2021-04-22T19:59:52.453617+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb stack Error: heroku-nextjs@1.0.0 start: `next start -p $PORT`
2021-04-22T19:59:52.453943+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb stack spawn ENOENT
2021-04-22T19:59:52.454262+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/app/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485168+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485187+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485192+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485211+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb pkgid heroku-nextjs@1.0.0
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485212+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb cwd /app
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485213+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb Linux 4.4.0-1088-aws
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485213+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485214+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb node v10.24.1
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485214+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb npm  v6.14.12
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485214+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485215+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485215+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485216+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485216+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! heroku-nextjs@1.0.0 start: `next start -p $PORT`
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485216+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485217+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485218+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the heroku-nextjs@1.0.0 start script.
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485233+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-04-22T19:59:52.485234+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
2021-04-22T19:59:52.528236+00:00 app[web.1]: npm timing npm Completed in 497ms
2021-04-22T19:59:52.528239+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-22T19:59:52.528240+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-04-22T19:59:52.528240+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-04-22T19_59_52_474Z-debug.log
2021-04-22T19:59:52.776725+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-04-22T19:59:52.840106+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: it is failing on `npm verb stack Error: heroku-nextjs@1.0.0 start: `next start -p $PORT``. you don't need to specify a port in your start script. it should do it automactically if you did it right from your root directory app.js, or index.js, whatever you decided to call it

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the same app works with no issue on my local computer. On my second question, do you know how i can actually see the content of the  .npm/_logs/2021-04-22T19_59_52_474Z-debug.log? That file doesnt seem to exist at all in my Heroku environment

Comment: unfortunately no. but you could try to find it in the logs in heroku logs directly from the dashboard. Sorry I couldn't have been of more help

Comment: "not found" -> next may mean u dont include that module in the package.json as you should. locally , if you rm ./node_modules/* then npm install then build then  "heroku local" you should get same errror in dev as u see in production ie not found -> next

Comment: so im deploying to heroku through GIT and i noticed my repo had package-lock.json in it as well. Deleting the packages-lock did the trick

Answer (score 0):

so im deploying to heroku through GIT and i noticed my repo had package-lock.json in it as well. Deleting the packages-lock did the trick